# Permission Denied errors as root in Koding VM (ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-13.04

I'm trying to debug why certain things aren't working in my koding VM, and first I'm trying to debug why I'm getting permission denied errors.

I'm fairly experienced with ubuntu, having it installed for four years on my laptop, and this is something I can't seem to figure out/find.

Here is one command I'm running:

```
tyzoid@vm-0:~$ sudo -s
root@vm-0:/index# find / > index
find: `/proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
find: `/proc/150/task/150/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/150/task/150/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/150/task/150/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/150/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/150/map_files': Permission denied
find: `/proc/150/fdinfo': Permission denied
find: `/proc/150/ns': Permission denied
find: `/proc/162/task/162/fd': Permission denied
find: `/proc/162/task/162/fdinfo': Permission denied
...
```

I can't seem to figure out why, after running as root, `find` still doesn't have access to certain folders.

There are also similar errors trying to restart apache (both as root and using sudo - which is why I'm investigating this in the first place)

Here is the `ls` of `/proc/`: http://pastebin.com/VvTE5RZV

Thanks in advance for anyone that can figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what are they doing, but it is as if these were shared resources (analogous to nfs mounts with root_squash set) and they are actually elsewhere, not owned by your vm. thus root has no right to them. the administrators must have reasons to prevent your access. however these are just information that you should be using userspace programs such as ps to query so should not affect the vm usability.